# Why am I "missing return statement" in one case, but not the other?

Tags: java

I am writing a code that will import a string of characters from a text file, analyze the string using a stack and determine which "language" the string belongs to based on whether or not it fits certain rules. Why is it in this case:

```
public static boolean checkL2(File file) throws IOException
{
    Stack l2Stack = new Stack();
    boolean bStart = false;
    char w;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s*");

    while(sc.hasNext()) //Load input from file onto stack
    {
        w = sc.next().charAt(0);

        if (w == 'A')
        {
            if (bStart == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                l2Stack.push('A');
            }
        }
        if (w == 'B')
        {
            bStart = true;
            if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                l2Stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I get an error telling my that I am missing a return statement, but not in this one:

```
 public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if (top == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

They look like very similar to me and I can't figure out why one works fine and the other does not. I would like to have the first bit of code return true or false based one whether the string fits the rules A^nB^n.

Comment: What does the first method return if `l2Stack.isEmpty()` is false?

Comment: In the second case, the `if`/`else` is setup in a way that you'll never reach a block where there isn't a `return`. In the first instance, it's possible to reach the end of the function without hitting a `return`.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but your `isEmpty()` method would look a lot nicer if it simply read `return top == -1;`

Comment: Put `return l2Stack.isEmpty();` at the end of the first method. That will fix it. Also, you can shorten `if (var == true)` to be `if (var)`

Comment: @4castle Why can it be shortened like that? Does Java assume true?

Comment: @Jes If `var` is a boolean, then it can be substituted for the boolean expression. `var == true` returns a boolean value just as `var` returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by the other answers, the reason why this is happening is because you declare your function as returning a boolean but it is possible for you to execute your function without actually hitting a return statement. For example imagine if Just to be a bit more explicit here is your code and where extra returns are needed:

```
    public static boolean checkL2(File file) throws IOException
    {
        Stack l2Stack = new Stack();
        boolean bStart = false;
        char w;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s*");

        while(sc.hasNext()) //Load input from file onto stack
        {
            w = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (w == 'A')
            {
                if (bStart == true)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    l2Stack.push('A');
                }
            }
            if (w == 'B')
            {
                bStart = true;
                if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    l2Stack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
//Added return 
    return false;
    }
```

This added return is necessary because imagine what would happen if when your while loop finishes, `l2Stack.isEmpty() == false`, in this case you would reach the end of a "non-void" function without returning anything which Java does not allow. There is no default return action, you must explicitly declare what you want to return in every case.

Answer (score 1):

They are not similar - in first example there is a chance that you will never return value (just when `l2Stack.isEmpty()` is not true or `w == 'B'`... etc) when in the second one you will **always** return something

You should add some default value to return like for example

```
    public static boolean checkL2(File file) throws IOException
    {
        ...

        if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        //return default
        return false;
    }
```

If the boolean is not enough you should return some other type like some kind of Enum

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you always `return` in an `if` statement. You **must** `return` from a method if it has a result type other than `void`. In your case you don't guarantee that *any* of the `if`s will be true thus you don't guarantee that a value will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

In your top method, it's possible for your code to not hit any of your if statements and return nothing.

If `l2Stack.isEmpty()` is false, your code has no return statement. Consider adding an else statement after that along with what your code should do.

Comment: Since you're new, 1 more piece of advice: Always try to format your answers by adding ` in front and after the code to make it look like `this` etc. Learn markdown and your answer will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as *compile-time* goes, the *compiler* cannot tell if `return` is explicit on all control paths, so emits an error.

This is despite your knowing (possibly) that the run-time behaviour is such that that is not the case.

(C and C++ allow this, placing the burden on the programmer. But this can cause problems if it turns out not to be the case, and the program behaviour is then *undefined*.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to return something in each case.

```
while(sc.hasNext()) //Load input from file onto stack
{
    w = sc.next().charAt(0);

    if (w == 'A')
    {
        if (bStart == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            l2Stack.push('A');
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (w == 'B')
    {
        bStart = true;
        if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            l2Stack.pop();
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing a method in Java that will return a value (boolean, string, etc.) the compiler **always** need to find a return at the first time it check the method. For example, using your method:

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    // The compiler can't be sure it will enter the if
    if (top == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

    // Here is expecting a return statement
}
```

So what you only need to do is to add a `return` at the end of your method so the compiler can be sure it will return something (even when you are sure it will never reach it).

Answer (score -1):

Suppose I have the following:

```
public int input(value) {
    if value > 10 {
        return value;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Value is not greater than 10.")
    }
 }
```

Is it clear how there's a path through the code that won't return a value? Any branch or conditional *must* return  a result in every code path. It helps (me, at least) to visualize paths through the code and double check that a return occurs in every possible path.