# Why does my code return false, regardless of input?

Tags: java

I am writing a code that will import a string of characters from a text file, analyze the string using a stack and determine which "language" the string belongs to based on whether or not it fits certain rules. The code below tests to see if an input follows the pattern A^nB^n (where n is greater than or equal to 0).

```
public static boolean checkL2(File file) throws IOException {
    Stack l2Stack = new Stack();
    boolean bStart = false;
    char w;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s*");

    while(sc.hasNext()) { //Load input from file onto stack
        w = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (w == 'A') {
            if (bStart == true) {
                return false;
            } else {
                l2Stack.push('A');
            }
        }
        if (w == 'B') {
            bStart = true;
            if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true) {
                return false;
            } else {
                System.out.print(l2Stack.pop());
            }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The input I'm testing with is `AAABBB`, which fits the rules, but my method is returning false. While debugging, I also noticed that it is iterating through twice (`System.out.print(l2Stack.pop());` prints 6 A's, not 3). I wanted to try to print the remaining contents of the stack (I thought it possibly wasn't empty for some reason) but couldn't figure out how to do that.

UPDATE: This is the code to print out the decision of whether the string belongs to a this language or not. I'm wondering if that's the problem?

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
if(checkL2(file)==true) {
    pw.print("This string fits the rules of Language 2");
}
if(checkL2(file)==false) {
    pw.print("This string does not fit the rules of Language 2");
}
pw.close();
```

Comment: Btw, you can just write `return l2Stack.isEmpty();` instead of `if (l2Stack.isEmpty() == true) { return true; } else { return false; }` (last lines).

Comment: @pzaenger It's funny, I said that [last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971858/why-am-i-missing-return-statement-in-one-case-but-not-the-other#comment63390159_37971858). They don't seem to be listening.

Comment: When I run your code against a file that contains `AAABBB`, it prints `AAA` and returns `true`. What, exactly, is the contents of your file?

Comment: BTW you don't have to check a boolean for true value (e.g. `l2Stack.isEmpty() == true`). Just check the boolean value itself (`l2Stack.isEmpty()`). Also, if you're returning true if the condition is true and returning false when it's false, then you can just return the condition. So, your final if construct can simply be rewritten as `return l2Stack.isEmpty();`. 8 lines reduced to a single line :) And you can wrap your Scanner in a try-with-resources block rather than closing it manually yourself.

Comment: Suppose you temporarily change your loop so that it's only this.  What is the program's output then?
`while(sc.hasNext()) //Load input from file onto stack
{
System.out.println(sc.next());
}`

Comment: @jason44107 It prints AAABBBAAABBB

Comment: @azurefrog I double and triple checked my file, it only contains AAABBB

Comment: These comments that are so quick to point out that your last `if` can be shortened to `return l2Stack.isEmpty()` haven't read carefully, since you want to return `false` if the stack is empty. On top of that, they aren't even helpful to the question at hand.

Comment: So, you are aware that you're running your method twice, right? So it'll print everything twice and it reads the file twice, etc.?

Comment: @azurefrog Okay, that makes sense now (and I can't believe I didn't think of that), but it is still printing out the false statement to the output file. Is there are better way to code for this (run the method once and print out either "yes this is that language" or "no it is not" based on the result)?

Comment: Use an else instead of a second if

Comment: @azurefrog it still prints with the false statement (ie not the language)

Comment: @NAMS Not correct. The last if construct was returning true if the stack was empty. And it's entirely relevant, as redundant logic and code simply muddies the water unnecessarily. The OP needs to learn how to write better code and it's entirely relevant to his learning to assist with this aspect.

Comment: Yeah, I ran his method with AAABBB file and it yielded AAA on the output and the return was true. Worked fine :)

Comment: @ManoDestra, I don't know what you did when you streamlined the code, but it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: You were calling checkL2 twice (see @4castle's answer below). You only needed to run it once and use an else construct instead of two if's. Voting to close due to minor error.

Comment: @ManoDestra The minor error is not a typographical error, it's a logic error. That is not a reason to close. Also, be very careful when making major edits to code in the question. It's best to only make code edits which pertain to the formatting.

Comment: @ManoDestra See [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/5743988) for more information on appropriate edits.

Comment: Apologies. Was a little overzealous in my formatting edits and ended up inadvertently fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To test your method without running it twice, use an `else` block:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
if(checkL2(file)) {
    pw.print("This string fits the rules of Language 2");
} else {
    pw.print("This string does not fit the rules of Language 2");
}
pw.close();
```

This can be streamlined using `try-with-resources`, and a ternary `bool ? trueValue : falseValue`

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile)) {
    pw.print(
      checkL2(file)
        ? "This string fits the rules of Language 2"
        : "This string does not fit the rules of Language 2"
    );
}
```

You can also streamline your other code:

```
public static boolean checkL2(File file) throws IOException {
    Stack l2Stack = new Stack();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s*")) {
        boolean bStart = false;
        while(sc.hasNext()) { //Load input from file onto stack
            char w = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (w == 'A') {
                if (bStart) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    l2Stack.push('A');
                }
            } else if (w == 'B') {
                bStart = true;
                if (l2Stack.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(l2Stack.pop());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return l2Stack.isEmpty();
}
```